# Create automatically a table from a data output in R

Tags: r

I have some trouble in R and hope to find some help here.

I have a data output from a loop of the following form, whereas the number of countries can vary:

```
> data
$Australia
   HITTypeId    HITId    Valid
1   123          555     TRUE

$India
   HITTypeId    HITId    Valid
 1  456          888     TRUE
```

Now what I am looking for, is to create a data table that gives my automatically something of the following form:

```
  country       HITTypeId      HITId    Valid
1  Austria         123          555     TRUE
2  Belgium         456          888     TRUE
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I think you've got a named `list` of `data.frames`.  You can use `do.call(rbind, yourlist)` to convert to a single `data.frame` where `country` will be the `row.names`.  If you can provide the output of `str(yourlist)` or `dput(head(yourlist))` you will likely get an even better answer

Comment: @justin, your comment was not visible when I answered. Post it as an answer so I can delete mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function:

```
do.call(rbind, data)
```

Comment: Whoever ends up with the answer of record should note that the country names will end up not as a variable but as row names, but that last piece can be added via `result$country <- rownames(result)` or something.